# How to change the login of a linux user?

Tags: linux

I have an user on my system named: **website1** with his password. I need to change the name of **website1** to **website2**. I don't want to remove it and then create a new user because I would like that website2 keep the exact same permissions as website1 on the system. I  only want to change the name.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is clearly a server administration question.  That said, just edit `/etc/passwd` (carefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usermod -l login-name old-name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with the `usermod -l` command. Check the `usermod` manual for more information.